# itextSharp PDF to text file in c# issue in Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-ec2, itext

I've a very strange issue and might be I'm not sure whats happen in the Amazon EC2 Instance.

I'm loading the PDF and extract the data and return the output as string using iTextsharp component(version 5.4.1). Its absolutely working fine in my local machine.

But when I deployed into Amazon EC2 instance (windows server 2008 R2) and its not working and getting error. I've captured the error in log file as below

```
java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line
iTextSharp.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: PDF header signature not found
```

My code was below and any help/suggestions would be really appreciated.

```
public static string parseUsingPDFBox(string PDFFilePath)
{
       PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(PDFFilePath);
       StringWriter output = new StringWriter();

       for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            output.WriteLine(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy()));

       reader.Dispose();
       return output.ToString();
}
```

I've all admin rights for EC2 instance and using .Net framework 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Please debug as follows:

Create a `FileInputStream` to `PDFFilePath`.

Read the `bytes` of this stream into an array.

Check the first five bytes.

On your local system, they're `'%'`, `'P'`, `'D'`, `'F'`, `'-'`.

On your Amazon EC2 instance, they aren't.

Check all the bytes to see what goes wrong.

Comment: No luck mate... I can get as byte[] length of PDFFilePath but again some issues arises.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I can get as byte[] length of PDFFilePath"? I don't understand your comment. Can you or can't you get the PDF as a byte array that starts with "%PDF-"?